# How do I get Gsuite account type via google API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

I am building google apps for marketplace. My app support only few Gsuite account type. So, While somebody signup to my app. I wanted to alert them their google account is valid for app or not.

To do this I require some API from google which check Gsuite account type.

Please let me know if you found any such API.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no adhoc Google API for this, but you can try this one:

Using API Explorer [plus.people.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=me&_h=1&) make an authorize request. Enter the userId parameter. Use 'me' if it's your personal email.

The response will contain a certain domain if they belong to one:

```
"domain": "NAME_OF_DOMAIN"
```

If `domain` doesn't show, they don't belong in any domain - default user.